# Looking for algorithm in file modification

Tags: java, file, io

Please advise for the algorithm let say If a file def.txt is created in C: then it should not be modified within 1 hour itself, if it is not modified within 1 hour I have to print in console "file is not modified" and If it is modified with in 1 hour itself then I have to print the statement "that file is modified" please advise how to write such algorithm in java or how to achieve this in java

Comment: You need that as a system service/daemon? Consider not using Java for this. It would be easier in different languages.

Comment: Please provide info on what tasks you have carried out

Comment: @LewsTherin I am stuck up ,Please advise..!!

Comment: @Andreas_D I want to make an function in java so that I can use it any where in my application,Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
File f = new File("/temp/t.txt");
long lastModified = f.lastModified();
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long difference = currentTime - lastModified;
// time is in milliseconds, one hour is 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds
long oneHour = 1000 * 60 *60;
if (difference > oneHour)
    System.out.println("file is not modified");
else
    System.out.println("that file is modified");
}
```

Comment: Kimaschewski..Thanks a lot, Really great effort, Thanks a lot could you please let me know one thing that I am reading the properties file will it work for property file also..!

Comment: PropertyFile propertyfile = new PropertyFile("TamperAlert.txt", "C:/abcstore/osErrlogs")

Comment: I don't know the PropertyFile class, it is not a Java standard class. But if it is somehow connected to a standard Java File class, it should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to monitor multiple files/directories you can implement a Watch Service, see: "Creating a Watch Service and Registering for Events" from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#register). Capturing ENTRY_CREATE and ENTRY_MODIFY events will allow you to act appropriately. On create record the creating time, and on modify, detect if the modification time is less or greater then an hour.

Comment: I am reading the property file ..PropertyFile propertyfile = new PropertyFile("TamperAlert.txt", "C:/abcstore/osErrlogs");..Now as per this a TamperAlert.txt is created in my C: , I want to track it that it should not be modified within 1 hour time frame

Answer (score 0):

On every attempt to modify the file, check first if the difference between `file.lastModified()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` is less then one hour in milliseconds.

You'll have to call this verification service (= an object providing a verify method) whenever needed.

Comment: @Andreas..I am reading the property file ..PropertyFile propertyfile = new PropertyFile("TamperAlert.txt", "C:/abcstore/osErrlogs");..Now as per this a TamperAlert.txt is created in my C: , I want to track it that it should not be modified within 1 hour time frame

Comment: Modified by the java application or modified in general?

Comment: modified by java application, in other words in TamperAlert.txt  there is a property name dfgh which value is o but if application modifies it in some scenario then the value of dfgh becomes 1 so I have to take care that it should not be modified within 1 hour itself